# I can only have 1 Unity app deployed on HoloLens

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I am facing a strange issue where I can only have 1 Unity app deployed on my HoloLens. For example:

First, I create new project called HoloLensFirstProject, import MRTK Foundation and Example, Setting up Unity for HoloLens development, select on of sample scene, build it and deploy it.

Secode, I create new project called HoloLensSecondeProject and do the same.

After deploying the second app, my first deployed app is gone and others app that I have develop before. Only the latest deployed app.

**Expected Behavior**

Multiple app can be deployed into HoloLens.

**Actual Behavior**

Only the latest app in installed on HoloLens

**Steps to reproduce**

- Create 2 projects with different name
- Import MRTK Foundation and Sample for both projects
- Setting up Unity projects for HoloLens development
- Pick one of sample scene for each projects to be deployed
- Deploy your first app
- Deploy you second app

**Environment**

- Unity 2018.3.11f1
- MRTK v2 RC1
- Visual Studio 2019
- Latest preview SDK
- Windows 10 (not insider preview)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It isn't sufficient to change the project name. You also have to change the package name under Project Settings → Player → UWP → Publishing Settings → Packaging → Package name.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, sorry for my late respond on this. I never had this kind of problem before, maybe this is because of newer version of Unity that had changes on how we should manage package name.

Comment: this didn't work for me. i changed thye package name in both apps but the issue still happens :(

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and this [solution by Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55779562) did not work for me. This only works if you have not deployed the app to your Hololens yet. In case that you have deployed the app already you need to delete the folder containing the data (for visual studio it is the folder containing the .sln file) and build it again.

You still have to change the package name before the build like in the solution from Jeff!

The reason for this is that in the first build the folder "build" is created. It contains the package information and will not change in further builds (for example if you change package name and build again in the existing directory).

Comment: You know about the commenting privilege which you do not have, so well that you can even put it into words. You are aware of the rule https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead . In that situation please do not decide to misuse a different mechanism (an answer) for something it is not meant for and which you are not allowed yet to do.